# how to remove the additional content in excel?

Tags: excel

eg: the line is `AF`.

the first line is:`<strong>Swarovski Earrings SWER002</strong><h2>Details</h2><div class=std">Swarovski Earrings SWER002 online hot sale. SWAROVSKI is a leading brand for a range of precisely-cut crystal and related luxury products  it represent the best modern luxe appeal. Our customers benefit from superior product quality and first-class services. The Swarovski Crystal range includes crystal glass sculptures and miniatures  jewelry and couture  home decor  and chandeliers. As a stockist of Swarovski  Our online store supply with best quality Swarovski jewelry  including Swarovski bracelets  earrings  rings  necklaces  go to our crystal paradise and pick the finest crystal elements  enjoy discounted prices and the incomparable Swarovski feeling."`

the following line format are all the same. now i want to remove `<strong>Swarovski Earrings SWER002</strong><h2>Details</h2>`form all the lines. and add a `</div>` label after the content? the content is too large so i can't drop down the format from the first line to the end. how should i do?

Comment: Can't you just resize the rows and pull down the formula?  Or select the cells using the keyboard and use Ctrl+d to fill down.

Comment: Have we misunderstood? Do you want to always replace the exact same text or rather everything before the closing </h2> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

I'm assuming that your text is in cell A1

Put the following formula in B1 and it should have the text that you want:

```
 =RIGHT(A1, len(A1)-(find("</h2>",A1)+4)) & "</div>"
```

This will copy everything to the right of the first occurrence of `</h2>` and append `</div>` to the end of that string.

Then, if you don't want to keep the original values you can copy column B and do a Paste Special then Paste Values.

Comment: i am sorry, i am a newbie. where to put you code in? thank you.

Comment: Type this into the cell just to the right of the cell that has the text in it that you want to change, but change all three of the A1's to the address of the cell that has your text in it.  Once this is done for the first one, you can copy and paste the new cell so that it is beside other lines and it will automatically update for them as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't drag the formula down, it's probably going to be tough to do this in `excel`.  When I have large files like that and I need to remove text, I use `sed` from `terminal`.

```
sed s/<strong>Swarovski Earrings SWER002</strong><h2>Details</h2>/g filename.csv > newfilename.csv
```

Where filename.csv is your current file, and newfilename.csv is where you want `sed` to output the updated file.

Here is a great resource for `sed` [Sed - An Introduction](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)
Now, adding the `div` to the end of the content is a bit tougher.  How is each block of content terminated?

Comment: if you can use sed, can't you use cat?

Comment: `cat` is used to display the contents of the file.  Commands like `grep` and `sed` are used to augment the file.

Comment: `cat` can also be used to combine files (i.e. add the text to the end), but since this is to multiple lines in the file it won't work anyway (not sure why I was thinking that last night, lol).